# Disable a spout for a particular duration of time

Tags: apache-storm

We have a requirement to disable spout for a specific interval (9:00 p.m to 9:00 a.m) every day. Currently we have written code in Spout that checks whether current time lies in that duration, if yes then do nothing, but this approach calls next tuple method continuously. Is there any better way to do the same (using config etc)?

Answer (score 1):

There is no better way. And even if the Spout is called over and over again, Storm will apply a sleep penalty if no output is emitted on a `next()` call, thus, a "busy wait situation" is avoided.

If you want to improve if the waiting penalty, you can implement an own `ISpoutWaitStrategy` and register for a topology via parameter `topology.spout.wait.strategy` (see `default.yaml`).

Answer (score 0):

What Matthias has suggested, will work well. Alternatively, you can also consider deactivating topology for this duration. Nimbus client can be used to programmatically deactivate the topology. nextTuple wouldn't be called on spout if the topology is deactivated. However, it will turn off all the spouts of topology which you may not want.